# Sumar de forma acumulativa en la misma consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

[image: Consulta Mysql]

Necesito sumar y restar las entradas y salidas de unidades en base a fechas, en donde en la columna SALDO refleja el resultado parcial pero no lo he logrado de manera correcta. Por que:

Como se ve en la imagen en la primera fila el SALDO DEBE SER 0 y después es 300, luego 650 y así sucesivamente...

Saludos, Gracias.

Comment: Puedes colocar el código como texto en la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la consulta del Saldo te falta colocar una condición más.
Debes comprobar que la fecha no sea anterior al rango que solicitas.

La consulta sería algo así:

```
SELECT
    a.fecha,
    a.Documento,
    a.`Proveedor / Cliente`,
    a.`Entrada / Salida Unidades`
    (
        SELECT
         sum(
            b.`Entrada / Salida Unidades`
        )
        FROM 
            v_movimiento_unidades_bodegas b
        WHERE
            a.cod_materia_prima = 'Audifonos'
            AND a.cod_bodega = 7
            AND b.Fecha <= a.Fecha
            AND b.Fecha >= '2018-10-18'          <---------- Condición que falta
    ) AS Saldo
    FROM 
        v_movimiento_unidades_bodegas AS a
    WHERE   
        a.cod_materia_prima = 'Audifonos'
        AND a.cod_bodega = 7
        AND a.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-18'
        AND '2018-12-19'
```

Comment: Gracias Jemonge.